# C# SSH Text, number Send?

Tags: c#, .net, ssh

when the script runs, wants me to enter numbers, Stuck on command 2, "SshCommand sc3" Not running command 3 ,

When the script runs, how long do you want to run it? she asks. he wants me to enter numbers
But I couldn't send the number, it doesn't come to that line.

```
   using (var client = new SshClient(host, user, pass))
    {
    client.Connect();
    SshCommand sc1 = client.CreateCommand("chmod +x xxx.sh");
    SshCommand sc2 = client.CreateCommand("./xxx.sh");
    SshCommand sc3 = client.CreateCommand("echo 500");
    SshCommand sc4 = client.CreateCommand("500");
    client.Disconnect();
    }
```

Comment: ideally we'd have at least a script (or a part that asks for input) to be able to reproduce your issue accurately

Comment: how can I do that. Thank you

Comment: For example: I'm setting it asks me to enter a number 500

chmod + x installer.sh
./installer
I need to print the number 500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of your flow is you `chmod` and start a script, pass some inputs to it and wait for it to finish. If I get your problem statement correctly, you might be better off using [`ShellStream`](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/blob/develop/src/Renci.SshNet/ShellStream.cs). This way your interactivity becomes an exercise or sening a command and [`Expecting`](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/blob/develop/src/Renci.SshNet/ExpectAction.cs) a certain response:

```cs
    /*
    #i used the following script on the other side to simulate activity:
    
    #!/bin/bash

    echo "Input time to sleep:" 
    read timeToSleep
    sleep $timeToSleep
    echo "We are done"
    */
using (var client = new SshClient(host, user, pass))
{
    client.Connect();
    var shell = client.CreateShellStream("bash", 80, 50, 1024, 1024, 1024); // I believe shell name is critical to get your control character sequences parsing right
    
    shell.Expect(new ExpectAction("#", (_) => // we wait for shell prompt here. if your shell is different you might need to tweak the regex
    {
        shell.WriteLine("chmod +x xxx.sh && ./xxx.sh");
    }));
    shell.Expect(new ExpectAction("Input time to sleep:", (_) => { 
        shell.WriteLine("5");
    }));
    shell.Expect(new ExpectAction("#", scriptOutput => {
        Console.WriteLine(scriptOutput);
    }));
    
    client.Disconnect();
}
```

As you havent shared the actual script that you run, i can't be more specific. Hopefully that sets you on track to flesh the details out.

Comment: I love you, it helped me a lot, thank you very much :)